# How can I edit multilingual inputs that use a Astrotomic / laravel-translatable library using AJAX request

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am using  Astrotomic / laravel-translatable for multi lang inputs
I made AJAX request but i cannot handle the inputs value

here is my AJAX code:

```
var formData = new FormData($("#itemForm")[0]);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        enctype: "multipart/form-data",
                        url: "{{ route('ajax.items.store') }}",
                        data: formData,


                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(data) {
```

here is the response

[response with dd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWYqt.png)

here is the Controller code:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $item = Item::findOrFail($request->id);
        $box = $this->unserializeForm($request);

        $data = json_decode($request, true);
        dd($box);
        $rules = [];

        foreach (config('translatable.locales') as $locale) {
            $rules += [$locale . '.name' => ['required', Rule::unique('item_translations', 'name')->ignore($request->id, 'item_id')]];
        }
        $request->validate($rules);
        $item->update($request->all());
```

i want to detect each locale value

[response without dd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tgXO.png)